# Unresolved reference: flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I have installed flask_sqlalchemy using pip.

I try to import it using the following line:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

But PyCharm does not recognize flask_sqlalchemy and when I run the code I get "NameError: name 'SQLalchemy' is not defined.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you installed it into the python environment that pycharm is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is `"NameError: name 'SQLalchemy' is not defined.` but what you've done in your file is `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

The difference is that you forgot to cap the A:

```
SQLAlchemy
SQLalchemy
```

Fix that in your file and the error should resolve.